# Null reference exception not all paths return a value in a Exit Function

Tags: .net, vb.net

On the code below the `Exit Function` shows a green line under it saying

Null reference exception not all paths return a value.

How do I exit and on exit make it return something?

Can you please help?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load()

        test()

    End Sub



    Function test() As String

        Exit Function

        Return ""

    End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `Exit Function` line and return what you want.  Or do you want to exit the program entirely?  They're two different things.

Comment: I  want to exit the function a return will do the trick. what do I use for a sub? Do I return also? thanks

Comment: For a `Sub` you use `Exit Sub`

Comment: For Subs you can also use return. There's actually no need for the Exit Statement at all.

Comment: @DominicKexel - its been too long to remember that!

Answer (score 3):

You usually just use [`Return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to exit a `Function` or `Sub` and to return a value from a `Function`.

```
Function MyMethod() As String
    Return "Some Stuff"
End Function
```

If you want to use [`Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to return a value from a `Function`, you have to "assign" a value to your `Function` (actually, the compiler will create a variable internally which will be returned):

```
Function MyMethod() As String
    MyMethod = "Some Stuff"

    Exit Function
End Function
```

However, you should just use `Return`. The `Exit` statement is just an old, deprecated VB6 legacy.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Return` also exits the function. You don't need to call (actually, you should never call) Exit Function. Also, you need to assign the result of the function to a variable if you want to use it.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()

    Dim result As String = test()
    'Do something with result

End Sub

Function test() As String

    Return "test string"

End Function
```